# 17.10 Display Settings - Missing Apply Button

Tags: drivers, display, button, displaylink

Just upgraded from 17.04 to 17.10 on a Dell laptop with a DisplayLink dock. I've reinstalled the latest 1.4 DisplayLink drivers - but I'm not sure this is a DisplayLink issue (Maybe it is). I'm also using the latest NVidia 384.90 driver.

When I make changes to my monitor scaling and position/order - I don't have get an Apply button. If I remove the laptops connection to the dock (and reboot) I do get the expected green Apply button in the top right hand corner after making changes.

Anyone have any idea where to start looking for a solution? I looks like there are people on the DisplayLink forums using 17.10 with the 1.4 driver - but again I'm not convinced this is a DisplayLink issue.

I tried logging back into a Unity session, but cannot make any changes to displays over there I get an error about not being able to read the monitor configuration.

[image: First Screen Shot of Settings page]

[image: Second Screen Shot of Settings page]

Comment: When I run `gnome-control-center display` and change the scale of my HDMI monitor I get: "(gnome-control-center:6990): display-cc-panel-WARNING **: Config not applicable: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Logical monitor scales must be identical"

Comment: Had this issue on Ubuntu 18.04, Ended up finding the same options in the NVIDIA X server settings application, under X Server Display Settings Configuration and was able to change them there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not it is the proper solution, I downloaded ARandr to modify Xrandr settings and was able to set up the proper display ordering and resolutions on my 2 external monitors outside of the gnome display settings.

I still have a bit of a scale issue, but I think that will be tolerable until I find a better way to set scale percentage.

Comment: After using arandr to config xrandr, my Apply button now appears when I make changes in gnome-control-center displays. Makes me wonder if the upgrade from 17.04 left something new for gnome unconfigured or a missing file? Maybe I wouldn't have had this issue with a clean install?

Comment: I did a clean install of 17.10 and I've the same issue when I connect 2 screens (1 to the HDMI port and 1 through the Dell USB-C Adaptor). Having only 1 ext screen connected still works fine.  Your workaround works fine!

Comment: This is not really a solution :-( and it doesn't seem to be working for me

Answer (score 0):

(Update: This solution doesn't work in the end (see my first comment) but I'm leaving it here in case it can maybe help someone.)

I have the same issue, what I did was edit `~/.config/monitors.xml` and change the scale from 1 to 2 for my monitor that had 4k resolution (the laptop's display, which is also the primary monitor in my case):

```
<logicalmonitor>
  <x>0</x>
  <y>0</y>
  <scale>2</scale> <!-- Scale was originally set to 1 -->
  <primary>yes</primary>
  <monitor>
    <monitorspec>
      <connector>eDP-1-1</connector>
      <vendor>SHP</vendor>
      <product>0x1476</product>
      <serial>0x00000000</serial>
    </monitorspec>
    <mode>
      <width>3840</width>
      <height>2160</height>
      <rate>59.996623992919922</rate>
    </mode>
  </monitor>
</logicalmonitor>
```

I then logged out and back in. Opening the display pannel now shows scale set to 200% for my 4k monitor.

Comment: Strike that, it actually didn't solve my issue. Well it did for my main monitor but the other monitors seem to also have scale == 2 :/ Actually also used ARandR in the end....